# jQTouch browser back button not working to separate index page

Tags: javascript, browser-history, jqtouch

Our jQTouch mobile site has a News & Events sections. Because of technical limitations with PHP, these sections had to live in a separate directory and jQTouch index pages (this can't be changed).

When I go from the main jQTouch index page to News or Events the browser back button doesn't work in iOS, Android, Safari and Firefox (oddly, Chrome works fine).

Do you know how to get the browser back button to work on the News and Events index pages?

Here is the main jQTouch index page of our mobile site:

http://bit.ly/ePbqHl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all shot-in-the-dark options, but it sounds like it might be similar to an older issue [like this one](http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=325) (which is from about a year ago). Are you using an older version of jQT?

A few possible things to try:

1) Grab the [latest version](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch) of jQT. This might introduce additional issues, but maybe worth swapping out the .js file to see if it resolves your problem.

2) Based on an even older post, your issue sounds like it might be related to the [dumbLoopStart function](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/jqtouch/W7CNuuf_61g/discussion). Maybe try altering/disabling this to see if it helps.

3) It's definitely more quiet on the [jQT Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jqtouch) as opposed to here, but you may want to post your issue there to see if others have experienced the same behavior.